# jquery datatable export buttons do not work?

Tags: jquery, button, datatable, export

The export buttons are not working in the jquery datatable. The data comes up fine. Below is the jquery code and the error in the console. What am I missing?

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
           $.ajax({
                        //type: "Get",
                        //url: "/customers/Index?handler=Json",      
                        //dataType: "json",
                        success: OnSuccess,
                    });
        });
        function OnSuccess(response) {
             $('#myTable').DataTable(
                {
                    
                    data: response.data,
                    columns: [
                        { "data": "Id" },
                        { "data": "description" },
                        { "data": "Date" },
                        { "data": "type" },
                        { "data": "status" }
                    ],
                    
                    scrollY: "400",
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                    ]
                });
        };
</script>
```

This is my _layout.cshtml

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.12.1/datatables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.12.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

I have 3.5.1 jquery. I am using Visual Studio 2019. Here's the error in the console:

```
  undefined
    datatables.min.js:120 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mData')
        at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (datatables.min.js:120:352)
        at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2:2976)
        at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2:1454)
        at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (datatables.min.js:120:305)
        at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2:2976)
        at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2:1454)
        at S.fn.init.u [as dataTable] (datatables.min.js:113:187)
        at l.fn.DataTable (datatables.min.js:203:482)
        at Object.OnSuccess [as success] (Index:152:27)
        at c (jquery.min.js:2:28294)
```

My html tags are well formed. It is still not working. Here's my html code:

```
<table id="myTable" class="display compact">

  <thead>
      
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011-04-25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011-07-25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009-01-12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012-03-29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008-11-28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012-12-02</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2012-08-06</td>
            <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**DataTables** works with formed tables which include `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags, else it will throw an *error*

Table like:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011-04-25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011-07-25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable(
            {
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                ]
            });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added my html code. I don't see anything there..